# Am I doing this right (method inside model) and how do I remove duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, model, unique

From my DB, I would like to interpret some data like so...

```
DataA xyz > I am data a
DataA zyx > I am data a
DataB xyz > I am data b
DataB zyx > I am data b
DataC xyz > I am data c
DataC zyx > I am data c
```

So in my model, I have...

```
def get_data

    if data.include? "DataA" then "I am data a"
    elsif data.include? "DataB" then "I am data b"
    elsif data.include? "DataC" then "I am data c"
    end

end
```

Which works, but I feel like I am doing it wrong.  Is there a correct way to achieve the above?

My second question is how to take the method and produce only unique records.  On my view, I have...

```
<td>
    <% Product.each do |f| %>
    <%= f.get_data.distinct %> 
    <% end %>
</td>
```

But I get the error

> undefined method `distinct' for "I am data c":String

Comment: It is not clear what `DataA xyz > I am data a ...` means. Write accurately what you mean. Which part represetnts a string?

Comment: I want any data that reads "DataA" to show "I am data a" on the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, when you see a bunch of if/elsif/elsif chained it's a code smell. I can think of two methods to write it cleaner:

```
def get_data
  case data
  when 'DataA' then 'I am data A'
  when 'DataB' then 'I am data B'
  when 'DataC' then 'I am data C'
  end
end
```

or

```
DATAS = {'DataA' => 'I am data A', 'DataB' => 'I am data B', 'DataC' => 'I am data C'}

def get_data
  ret_val = nil
  DATAS.each{|k,v| ret_val = v if k.includes?(data)}
  ret_val
end
```

---

For your second question, you'll need to query for unique values and then call the get_data method

```
<% Product.distinct(:data).each do |f| %>
  <%= f.get_data %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: I like the DATAS method, but how do I get it to include the text, not just match it?  I have tried DATAS.include?[persons_entitled], but that fails

Comment: @JimBob, sorry, I missed the "includes?" part of the question (I was just trying to reduce the if/else chain). I'll update my answer, but it won't be that clean to use include

Comment: "Datas" is not a word. "Data" is already [plural/uncountable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/data) :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague, but i'll try to answer it with what I think you mean. For the first question, if you want to be able to save only unique records, you can use `validates :<attribute>, uniqueness: true` on the model, which will make sure it's unique before saving it to the database. I'm not sure if this is what you meant, please elaborate a bit more on what `get_data` does and why you need to do that.

For the second question, you are returning strings, and the String class does not have the method `distinct`, that method belongs to `Array`, so you could do something like `result = []` and then `if <whatever> then arr << "Some string" end`. Again, share some more info so we can give a better answer.